# Error: Cannot find module 'express-session' when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, express, dependencies

I am a beginner and I am trying to deploy my node app to Heroku. 
From what I understand in the log below Heroku has trouble reading the express-session dependency. 
So I checked my package.json file and it wasn't in there, even though it was 'requiring' it in my app.js file. It also has been running just fine locally with nodemon without express-session.

Assuming that this may cause the error message I added 'express-session' in the dependencies. 
Then I ran in the CL npm install express-session, npm install, git add. & git commit and then pushed it back to Heroku.
Yet, the same error still shows up.

These are my dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "simplyfly",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "ejs": "^2.3.1",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "method-override": "^2.3.2",
    "pg": "^4.3.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "request": "^2.55.0",
    "sequelize": "^2.0.5",
    "sequelize-cli": "^1.7.0",
    "cool-ascii-faces": "~1.3.x",
    "express-session": "^1.7.6"
  }
}
```

And here is my log:

```
2015-06-15T20:13:20.488264+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2015-06-15T20:13:20.488268+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
2015-06-15T20:13:20.488265+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
2015-06-15T20:13:21.385482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-15T20:13:21.421482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-15T20:13:33.850256+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:13:42.056575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=cbef7e0e-24cb-45f1-9934-7a326a514ed4 fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:13:48.199162+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=7ba21844-6623-4d9c-af76-ffa60cad4fbd fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:26:58.464510+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 36f1770 by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:26:58.464510+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:26:58.548710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-15T20:26:58.512202+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-06-15T20:26:58.512230+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-06-15T20:27:02.685211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-06-15T20:27:04.742124+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-06-15T20:27:04.742151+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295237+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:338
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295241+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295242+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295244+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express-session'
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295246+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295248+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295250+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295251+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:11:15)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295255+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295257+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295256+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2015-06-15T20:27:05.295259+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
2015-06-15T20:27:06.155893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-15T20:27:06.156698+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-15T20:27:06.140225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-15T20:27:09.292073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-06-15T20:27:11.100911+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.100933+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975393+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:338
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975397+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975399+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975401+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express-session'
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975402+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975404+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975405+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975408+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:11:15)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975407+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975410+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975411+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975412+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975414+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
2015-06-15T20:27:11.975415+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
2015-06-15T20:27:13.067329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-15T20:27:13.052249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-15T20:27:19.506077+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:27:46.543780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=3df4bc96-feb7-48c6-a52b-ded903ae154e fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:34:06.988969+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-06-15T20:34:06.988997+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-06-15T20:34:06.911574+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d8ce9d8 by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:34:06.911574+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:34:07.186442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-15T20:34:09.816487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-06-15T20:34:11.760020+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-06-15T20:34:11.760047+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-06-15T20:34:12.637513+00:00 app[web.1]: I'm listening
2015-06-15T20:34:27.737044+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:35:10.211701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-06-15T20:35:10.211701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-06-15T20:35:11.059387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-15T20:35:11.047891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-06-15T20:35:49.365371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=596720e4-470d-4c1b-9beb-88830c2530b4 fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:35:54.100625+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=3304c0b0-4ea8-4b4c-9b15-68018303143a fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:35:59.738039+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=f0c96f6c-e017-443b-b3fc-c470ea172b09 fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:35:56.928372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=bd37d2d7-4e40-4a83-ae4c-c4bb8d77ebab fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:47:13.464465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=11dae041-9755-46f3-8120-62185021f166 fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T20:50:18.169656+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by c.kazbour@gmail.com
2015-06-15T20:50:21.182682+00:00 heroku[run.7063]: Awaiting client
2015-06-15T20:50:21.207522+00:00 heroku[run.7063]: Starting process with command `bash`
2015-06-15T20:50:21.498626+00:00 heroku[run.7063]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-15T20:56:22.967959+00:00 heroku[run.7063]: Process exited with status 130
2015-06-15T20:56:22.982990+00:00 heroku[run.7063]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-15T20:56:34.860491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=03ab7279-9f54-47f3-bd78-66a1f8878f11 fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-15T22:06:06.911203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-15T22:06:09.190364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-06-15T22:06:11.192311+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-06-15T22:06:11.192332+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-06-15T22:06:12.342276+00:00 app[web.1]: I'm listening
2015-06-15T22:07:09.670256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-06-15T22:07:09.670341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-06-15T22:07:10.700825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-15T22:07:10.687467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-06-15T23:35:04.950903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-15T23:35:10.538060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-06-15T23:35:13.112171+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-06-15T23:35:13.120415+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-06-15T23:35:16.100005+00:00 app[web.1]: I'm listening
2015-06-15T23:36:10.835815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-06-15T23:36:10.835815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-06-15T23:36:11.797436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-06-15T23:36:11.815434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-16T00:28:50.659338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=4412f0e2-1e68-4ec0-9a62-47c3f5151cbb fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-16T00:28:55.687612+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=b3487f82-36f7-4138-9247-30a8a45effd9 fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-16T00:28:58.049747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=simplifly.herokuapp.com request_id=69e2ddf4-9c28-42f5-8aec-47cf51bb4109 fwd="50.141.68.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Am I reading the log file wrong and the error is somewhere else? Thank you so much for any pointers in the right direction! I have been reading tutorials and googled this but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Adding express-session to package.json solved my problem.

```
"express-session": "1.14.2"
```